# ASP.NET Web API return data in JSON or XML by checking Request content type

Tags: asp.net-web-api, content-negotiation

While using ASP.NET Web API, how can I check request content type whether it is application/xml or application/json?  I know about content negotiation in ASP.NET Web API but it's not going to work with me because I get the data from database in XML format only.  So if I can check request content type, I can convert XML to json when request content type is XML otherwise simply return XML.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to inspect the **Accept** header to see if they want JSON vs. XML back.  To do so you need to inspect the context's request headers. There are at least two ways to do that.

**Option #1 - Implement inside of API controller method**

To do that inside your API method inspect what's inside of:

```
this.ControllerContext.Request.Headers.Accept
```

---

**Option #2 - Use an ActionFilterAttribute**

With that you can also inspect the  to see what the client is wanting to get back.

```
public class HttpUserContextFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{        
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
         //Here is where you can inspect the headers
         //e.g. look into actionContext.Request.Headers.Accept
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new ApiController class, by inherited from apiController, add the JsonContent action.

```
public class ApiCustomController: System.Web.Http.ApiController {
    public class JsonContent : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute {

        public override bool IsValidForRequest(
            ControllerContext controllerContext
            , System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo) {

            var Request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
            string requestedWith = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] ?? string.Empty;
            return string.Compare(requestedWith, "XMLHttpRequest", true) == 0
                && Request.ContentType.ToLower().Contains("application/json");
        }
    }

}
```

Then in your controller, inherit from the custom controller class, "ApiCustomController" and use the ActionMethodSelectorAttribute "JsonContent".

```
public class IngredientsController : App_a_matic.Controllers.ApiController {
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    [JsonContent]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
 }
```

This you are sending in the "contentType: 'application/json'" like:

```
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/Products/Ingredients'
            , contentType: 'application/json'
            , dataType: 'json'
            , type: 'GET'
            , success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    })
```

As opposed to just using getJson.